# Extract data from SQL Server in SharePoint

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I need to query a database (SQL Server 2005) to get data into a Sharepoint 2007 website (using list would be nice). I have MOSS installed.

I tried using Sharepoint Designer to create a ListView with a database connection... But I keep getting this cryptic error: "The server returned a non specific error when trying to connect to get data from the data source".

The connection with username/pass works and it shows me the table that I want; that error appears when I select "Show Data" on the connection.

Can someone help me out on this, please? I'm a beginner and would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use Either BDC to fetch the data from SQL server or create a custom webpart and then by using the ADO.Net pull the data from SQL Server.